# Coldfusion 10 cookie data missing

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am transitioning from a Coldfusion 9 to Coldfusion 10 server.  I have noticed an issue that my login cookie (generated from .NET) is losing data when I read it in Coldfusion.  IE, a cookie that is supposed to read:

> EMAIL=user@hotmail.com&ID=9994171&CONTENT_SECURITY=MBR CO CFO PFS MC CL RE STF PA SP SC HCC&FIRST_NAME=Jack&LAST_NAME=Smith&FULL_NAME=Jack Smith&CHAPTER=047&TITLE_SEGMENT=Mid-Level/Execu&TITLE_SEGMENT_DESC=Other&PAID_THRU=5/31/2014 12:00:00 AM&MEMBER_TYPE=STF&MEMBER_STATUS=A&IS_MEMBER=False&ELIGIBLETOJOIN=False&IS_STAFF=Yes

is only reading in CF10 as:

> EMAIL

It seems that any special character causes this as I'm seeing it on spaces, =, etc.  Has anyone had this issue or have some input on the cause of this?  I don't want to have to re-write my security due to this but I'm having a hard time understanding this switch.

Comment: How are you getting your information about the content of the cookie?  Are you reading it with a text editor before and after you run the coldfusion page?

Comment: I am reading it via the Firefox->Options->Privacy->Remove Individual Cookies to see which cookies are populated.  Then I'm dumping the "#cookie#" variable to see what's in the cookie through Coldfusion's eyes.  It's in the 'dump' that I see the cutoffs on any cookie value that has a space or =.  It might have more triggers, but that's all I've noticed.  I also set a cookie via <cfcookie> and this displayed in the dump fine even though it had spaces.

Comment: If you look at the same cookie using firefox after it's been read by ColdFusion, does it still have the original content?

Comment: Yes, the cookie is the same in firefox as well as any .NET applications that require that cookie.

Comment: Which part of that string is the name of the cookie and which part is the value?  Is it a cookie named "EMAIL" with a value equal to "user@hotmail.com&ID=9994171&CONTENT_SECURITY=MBR CO CFO PFS MC CL RE STF PA SP SC HCC&FIRST_NAME=Jack&LAST_NAME=Smith&FULL_NAME=Jack Smith&CHAPTER=047&TITLE_SEGMENT=Mid-Level/Execu&TITLE_SEGMENT_DESC=Other&PAID_THRU=5/31/2014 12:00:00 AM&MEMBER_TYPE=STF&MEMBER_STATUS=A&IS_MEMBER=False&ELIGIBLETOJOIN=False&IS_STAFF=Yes"?

Comment: I didn't even include the name of the cookie which is MSC.  The VALUE of the cookie is what I included above.

Comment: I just ran into this today on CF 10/Ubuntu/Apache.

Comment: One thing you can try is to URL Encode the cookie before setting it.  Coldfusion should then be able to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the GetHTTPRequestData() method.

```
_cookie = GetHttpRequestData().headers.cookie;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this same issue out.  We are working with a cookie value with a fixed length.  For some reason CF10 isn't displaying an individual cookie value, so we grabbed a string of all the cookies, then did a search on that for where the cookie value starts and extracted the value.
(credit to Sanjeev for getting me started in the right direction)

```
<cfset allcookies = GetHttpRequestData().headers.cookie>

<!--- Finds the string where your cookie starts --->
<cfset yourCookie = Find("sampleSting", allcookies) >

<!--- Grabs a six digit number after the seven digit cookie string. --->
<cfset yourVariable = MID(allcookies,(sampleString+7),6)>
```